# Atomic transactions using Flask before_request and after_request

Tags: python, flask, py2neo

I am trying to make **py2neo** transactions with **Flask** atomic by means of using `before_request` to start a transaction and `after_request` to commit or rollback, depending on the response status code.

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, app, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, abort
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request
from py2neo import Graph
import models

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

def get_db():
    return Graph(password="secret")

graph = get_db()
tx = None

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    tx = graph.begin()

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    if response.status_code >= 400:
        tx.rollback()
    else:
        tx.commit() # Error line
```

The problem is that modifications to module variable `tx` made on `before_request` seem not to be noticeable by `after_request`, so I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'commit'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. All I had to do is to use **flask** `g` object to store `tx` so it can be available for all methods called along the request:

```
from flask import Flask, request, app, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, abort
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request
from py2neo import Graph
import models

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

def get_db():
    return Graph(password="SteppenWolf1")

graph = get_db()

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.tx = graph.begin()

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    tx = g.get('tx')
    if response.status_code >= 400:
        tx.rollback()
    else:
        tx.commit()

    return response
```